# The method managedQuery(Uri, String[], String, String[], String) from the type Activity is deprecated

Tags: java, android, deprecated

When I compile the following code

```
cursor = activity.managedQuery( imageUri, proj, null, null, null );
```

I get following warning

> The method managedQuery(Uri, String[], String, String[], String) from the type Activity is deprecated

The code is working fine. What should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 43):

The `managedQuery` method is deprecated, meaning it should no longer be used and there is an updated method available. The replacement for this is `getContentResolver().query()`:

```
cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, proj, null, null, null);
```

You can normally find out why the method is deprecated, and what you should use instead, by a quick Google of the method name, or depending on how good the javadoc is it may inform you through your IDE.

Comment: Thanks! It works nicely. getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

Answer (score 7):

The above answer is very apt. I just wanted to add to this thread more info as to why `managedQuery` is deprecated. 
[**Here**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)
is a nice explanation for why the `managedQuery` is replaced by `getContentResovler().query()`